# Writing a Gradle for a previous Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just started an android project for school, and I have to edit an android application that was built by previous students. I was given source files and apk but no `gradle`.

I imported into Android Studio and tried to run the build when I saw that I couldn't. I have looked up documentation online for the past 4 days and have so far come up with nothing other than downloading the `gradle-2.7` files and running:

```
build gradle
```

in my computers shell.

Is there an easy way to build a `gradle`? Perhaps some tools or such? Or will I have to go through the files and write all the `gradles` myself?

Comment: gradle file in necessary for android studio. You have to import gradle file first.

Comment: is your source is coded in eclipse

Comment: I have no idea what my source code is in? Is there a way to find out? @warlock And what do you mean by import gradle? Did I not already do that after using `gradle build` ? @ChiragSavasani?

Comment: take a screen shot of the  root directory structure of the source code, and paste here

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9ce86eb8c7a89a6b5d4ac30a4379cfde

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses a Gradle wrapper to fully integrate the Android plugin for Gradle. You can build your Android apps from within Android Studio and from the command line on your machine or on machines where Android Studio is not installed.

Android studio comes bundled with gradle and in the screenshot I can see gradel folder, gradlew and gradlew.bat and build.gradle files. So (hopefully) all you need to take care is build.gradle files.

I would strongly suggest you to go through [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

If you have time go through this [course](https://www.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867)

Comment: The only reason there are gradle files in the folder is because I ran `gradle build` in the command line while on the root of the project